# Akka start and access actors returned data

Tags: java, akka

I've actor `MainActor` which initializes and send messages for two other sub and expecting to get a result back. So `MainActor` has two child actors `SubActorA` and `SubActorB`.

Basically I want to build a model when data from sub actors has arrived I would be able to access it somewhere on a higher level (class which initialized `MainActor`)

For example I have 100 ms for both tasks. If `SubActorA` has returned data in 70 ms but `SubActorB` needs more time it would have 30 ms more and after all tasks will be abandoned, but I still interested in data and would like to have an access for it even if some of the sub tasks has time outed.

Questions:

1. How do I limit whole execution for 100 ms so that in future I would be able to access data partially from each actor?
2. How do I access data from actor on highest level? I cannot all the time push data to higher level again and again by extending from `UntypedActor` and sending messages to higher level. I have tried to create a `WrapperHandler` which would initialize `MainActor`but unfortunately getting exception `You have to use one of the 'actorOf' factory methods to create a new actor.` Of course I can do that using `actorOf` method and invoke `.tell()` method to send a message to the actor which starts all the job. But how do I get a response back if I am not extending `UntypedActor` and not overriding `onRecieve()` method anymore?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything in Akka is based on message-passing.  If you want to get data from an actor, you ask for it (send a message) and the actor will (maybe) reply (send another message).

Fortunately, Akka provides a helper called `ask` that lets you send messages from outside an actor and receive the reply as a `Future`.  You send a message via the ask helper to your `MainActor` from outside your actor hierarchy (or wherever you instantiated `MainActor`), the `MainActor` will reply with your data.

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.9/java/untyped-actors.html#Ask__Send-And-Receive-Future

Comment: thanks a lot! whom my `MainActor` should reply? I am trying reply to `getContext().parent().tell(message, getSelf());` but it fails with timeout. Do you know possible reason?

Comment: You have to reply to sender.

Comment: but since `MainActor` received current message (which it wants to forward outside of actor) from `SubActorA` in my understanding reference to sender would produce an infinite loop?

Comment: I mean that you cannot rely on `sender()` if you have more than one level of hierarchy because one actor might receive many messages from different SubActors at the same time. You can pass a listener with a constructor but again, how to return answer outside the actors world in this case?

Comment: You ask for data and immediately return it to `sender()`.  If that data is several levels down in your hierarchy then you'll have to ask at each level or use `forward`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, probably `forward()` is exactly that I need!

Comment: I managed to receive message back outside actor world. What I would like to do next, is to send one message and receive few messages back. How do I achieve that functionality. because right now one of my messages is coming back. Thanks!